# Calling elisp functions from inside yasnippet

Tags: yasnippet

I created a yasnippet that calls a function:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: print
# key: pr
# --
`(cperl-print)`
```

The function code:

```
(defun cperl-print ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((current (point))
          (end (line-end-position)))
    (if (< current end)
      (insert "print")
      (progn
        (insert "print ;")
        (backward-char 1))
      )))
```

Unfortunately, `backward-char` doesn't produce any effect when called from inside yasnippet. When the function is called directly, it works. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The snippet writing tutorial expressly discourages the use of `insert` within backquotes... Per the snippet writing tutorial https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html :  "**Note: backquote expressions should not modify the buffer.**  Please note that the lisp forms in backquotes should **not** modify the buffer, doing so will trigger a warning. For example, instead of doing ..."

Comment: @lawlistWhat to do if I need to insert different text depending upon the environment? His example is too primitive.

Comment: In older versions of `yasnippet`, it was possible to return a string with a place holder of where to end such as `"print$0;"` and that would have solved your problem -- along with there being no need to use `(insert "....")`, i.e., just return the string itself.  However, that previous solution no longer works because there is an args out of range error.  If @npostavs is still active on this forum, then he may have a solution for you.  If a satisfactory answer is not forthcoming in a reasonable period of time, then you may wish to consider submitting an Issue on Github to obtain some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#org24f6fba), there is `type` directive:

> If the type directive is set to command, the body of the snippet is interpreted as lisp code to be evaluated when the snippet is triggered.

So, I just used it and it worked.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: print
# key: pr
# type: command
# --
(let* ((current (point))
        (end (line-end-position)))
  (if (< current end)
    (insert "print")
    (progn
      (insert "print ;")
      (backward-char 1))))
```